# Get the name of user who updated post

Tags: users

Does anyone know how to get the name of the user who last updated a post/page please? (Not the post author). I can see that it is visible in the post/page revisions but don't know how to access it.

Any ideas/help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
the_modified_author();
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_author

```
<p>This post was last modified by <?php the_modified_author(); ?></p>
```